# Combining INSERT SELECT with constants

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert records into a table where one of the columns comes from another table.

The other two columns are the same for each record.

All three columns are keys.

I'm trying this embedded INSERT SELECT which I see is not allowed?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C)
    VALUES (1,(SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM TABLE) ,2)
```

Answer (score 19):

Your syntax is off - this is the correct syntax for this:

```
Insert Into Table
        (Column_A, Column_B, Column_C)
Select  1, Column_Name, 2
From    OtherTable
```

Comment: Thanks!  How would I add a distinct to that column name?

Comment: @user1327418 To add a distinct, just change the select statement to be: `Select Distinct 1, Column_Name, 2 From ...`

Comment: Or maybe better to just throw those distinct values into a temp table and work from there?

Answer (score 0):

I would post a comment but I don't have enough 'status' yet.

The insert below works in PostgreSQL.  What database are you using?

```
insert into people_experiences (qty, created_at, updated_at, person_id, experience_id) values (1, now(), now(), (select id from people where first_name='Joseph'), (select id from experiences where experience='MS'));
INSERT 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can even use this

```
Insert Into Table
(Select  "value-1" as column, "value-2" as column, ot.* from otherTable ot)
```

for two column i want constant values and rest should be use as it is.

Note: Insert select will not allow virtual column.